# clang-format multiline array definition and ending braces

Tags: c++, clang-format

I'm using clang-format (through VScode) and it's refactoring my array definition code this way

```
int my_array[] = {
    OPTION1, 2,
    OPTION2, 4,
    END};
```

while I would like the ending braces to go to the next line

```
int my_array[] = {
    OPTION1, 2,
    OPTION2, 4,
    END
};
```

I can't seem to find the right setting. Any idea how could I get this?

Comment: Can you show your current .clang-format file?

Comment: also I'm not sure what you want is possible with clang format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by adding `// clang-format off`

```cpp
// clang-format off
int my_array[] = {
    OPTION1, 2,
    OPTION2, 4,
    END
};
// clang-format on
```

However it is not the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

1. `Cpp11BracedListStyle: false` disables moving the closing brace
2. Add a trailing comma to the last element of the array:

```c
int my_array[] = {
    OPTION1, 2,
    OPTION2, 4,
    END,
};
```